# on submit, redirect window based on dropdown value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Still very new to JavaScript so apologies if this is obvious, but I cant find the answer on here.

I am trying to redirect when the submit button is clicked based on the value of a dropdown option.

```html
<html>
<body>

  <h1>test</h1>

  <select id="eventChoice" style="width:35vw;">
    <option value="theatre">Theatre</option>
    <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="open mic">Open Mic</option>
  </select>

  <button id="eventSubmit">Submit</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

var submit = document.getElementById('eventSubmit');
var choice = document.getElementById('eventChoice');

submit.onClick function(){
  
  if (choice.selectedIndex == "Comedy"){
    location.href="http://google.com";
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be great. Oddly enough I can do this in jQuery, but I am trying to learn as much javascript as possible.

Comment: What exactly isn't working? what exactly do you want it to do that it's not now?

Comment: The javascript element. It doesnt redirect if comedy is selected in the dropdown

Comment: @Liam can't you see why this code isn't working? `choice.selectedIndex == "Comedy"` will never return `true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Tom Bird: There are syntax errors.

1. '=' operator is missing for the onclick handler
2. the Click API is 'onclick', it was wrongly typed as 'OnClick'.

You can modify it like this and it should work.

```
submit.onclick = function(){

    // selectedIndex for comedy is 1, select option are zeroth-index based.
    if (choice.selectedIndex == 1){
      location.href="http://google.com";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
var submit = document.getElementById('eventSubmit');
var choice = document.getElementById('eventChoice');

submit.onclick = function(){
  var choiceselected = choice[choice.selectedIndex].text;
  if (choiceselected === "Comedy"){
    window.location.href="http://google.com";
  }
};
```

```html
 <h1>test</h1>

  <select id="eventChoice" style="width:35vw;">
    <option value="theatre">Theatre</option>
    <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="open mic">Open Mic</option>
  </select>

  <button id="eventSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: what have you changed, why have you changed it, etc?

Comment: @Yasir smbd downvoted all the answers, seems to be for no apparent reason. upvoted your answer back to normal ;)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<body>

  <h1 id="selectedOption">test</h1>

  <select id="eventChoice" style="width:35vw;">
    <option value="theatre">Theatre</option>
    <option value="comedy">Comedy</option>
    <option value="music">Music</option>
    <option value="open mic">Open Mic</option>
  </select>

  <button id="eventSubmit">Submit</button>


<script type="text/javascript">

var submit = document.getElementById('eventSubmit');
var choice = document.getElementById('eventChoice');
var selectedOption= document.getElementById('selectedOption');

submit.onclick =(function(){
  selectedOption.append(" "+choice[choice.selectedIndex].value);
  if (choice[choice.selectedIndex].value == "comedy"){
    window.location ="http://google.com";
  }
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what have you changed, why have you changed it, etc?

Comment: I have bound the onclick event and got the selected drop down vale for comparison, I have also used === triple equal for the if condition

Comment: @Arsalan Akhtar smbd downvoted all the answers, seems to be for no apparent reason. upvoted your answer back to normal ;)

Comment: This is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48884196/542251), notice the context and explanation. This is just a dump of code and is a bad answer